# Prestashop 1.6 - Create Forms with more than 1 submit buttons

Tags: php, tabs, admin, prestashop

I'm trying to implement a form in a tab on the back office on prestashop 1.6.

I've succeeded creating the form using the Helper class and all works fine. However, of what I see the helper class only allows 1 submit button. For my needs I need to use more than 1 that perform different actions on the postProcess() part of the controller. Any help on achieving that would be much appreciated. Here is my render form that works with a single submit button:

```
    public function renderForm()
           {
         $fields_form = array(
                'form' => array(
                    'legend' => array(
                        'title' => $this->l('Contact details'),
                        'icon' => 'icon-envelope'
                    ),
                    'input' => array(
                        array(
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'label' => $this->l('Account owner'),
                            'name' => 'BANK_WIRE_OWNER',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'type' => 'textarea',
                            'label' => $this->l('Details'),
                            'name' => $this->l('test2'),
                            'desc' => $this->l('Such as bank branch, IBAN number, BIC, etc.')
                        ),
                        array(
                            'type' => 'textarea',
                            'label' => $this->l('Bank address'),
                            'name' => 'BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS',
                        ),                  
                    ),
                    'submit' => array(
                        'title' => $this->l('Save'),                
                    )
                ),
            );

            $helper = new HelperForm();
            $helper->show_toolbar = false;
            $helper->table =  $this->table;
            $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
            $helper->default_form_language = 1;
            $helper->fields_value['BANK_WIRE_OWNER'] = "";
            $helper->fields_value['test2'] = "";
            $helper->fields_value['BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS'] = "";
            $this->fields_form = array();
            $helper->submit_action = 'test';

            return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want to achieve. Why don't you create a different form since it's a different action?

Comment: Hello. I need to perform different actions on the form fields based on the button click. I'm performing some advanced POST processing in the controller and my form needs to have 4 buttons. I talked with a dev in Prestaforums and he told me it's not possible to achieve what I Want programmatically so he adviced me to use raw code. It worked fine but I wondered if there was a better way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would have answered the same thing that this dev :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create more forms on the same screen.

```
return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form1, $fields_form2, $fields_form3));
```

Or if you really need to reuse the same form, you can add `<select>` as a last form element, that will give you a choice of action to be executed by submit button.